# Problems with joining two tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables. `user(user_id, username, password, age)` and `comment(comment_id, comment, user_id(foreign key))`.

I'm trying to get username from user, using the `user_id` provided in comment.

My query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM comments)";
```

I'm getting null. Is my brain working poorly or is it something else I messed up?

I just want to display all comments after each other, with the username before it.

Comment: Use IN instead of "=" .  `SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM comments)`;

Comment: Also you will probably want a where clause for the comments, otherwise you will get all user_id's from comments.  Also please tag your question with the version of SQL you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of `"="` .

```
    SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM comments);
```

OR you can use a proper join, something like:

```
    SELECT username FROM user,comments WHERE user.user_id = comments.user_id
```

Comment: Those two statements aren't the same thing. The second one is very likely to produce much more rows than the first one (and please use an explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the implicit joins in the `where` clause)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a join - a join would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user u JOIN comments c ON u.user_id = c.user_id";
```

When you use a subquery with `=`, the subquery must return one value.  To show all related records in a related table, use `JOIN` instead.